# CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe, windows phone app using phonegap

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows app in phonegap 3.5.0 on windows 8. I am creating test app as per commands given in phonegap documentation.
 I get error while i connect device or try to run on emulator, as `CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe...
C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\deploy.js(96, 5) WshShell.Exec: The system c
annot find the file specified.`
my command prompt script is as below:

```
C:\>cordova create hello1 com.example.hello1 HelloWorldHP
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorldHP" and id "com.example.hell
o1" at location "C:\hello1"

C:\>cd hello1

C:\hello1>cordova platform add wp8
Checking wp8 requirements...
Creating wp8 project...
platformRoot = C:\Users\IT\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.5.0\wp8
repoRoot = C:\Users\IT\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.5.0
Creating Cordova-WP8 Project:
        App Name : HelloWorldHP
        Namespace : com.example.hello1
        Path : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
CREATE SUCCESS : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8

C:\hello1>cordova build
Running command: C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat

WARNING: [ --debug | --release ] not specified, defaulting to debug...
Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty
List;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
  Creating file CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap
BUILD SUCCESS.

C:\hello1>cordova build wp8
Running command: C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat

WARNING: [ --debug | --release ] not specified, defaulting to debug...
Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty
List;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
  Creating file CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap
BUILD SUCCESS.

C:\hello1>C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat --debug

Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty
List;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
BUILD SUCCESS.

C:\hello1>C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat --release

Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Release
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = cmd /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild" "
C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;V
erbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Release"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Release\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
  Creating file CordovaAppProj_Release_AnyCPU.xap
BUILD SUCCESS.

C:\hello1>C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\clean.bat
Cleaning cordova project...

C:\hello1>cordova emulate wp8
Running command: C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.bat --emulator
WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debu
g.

Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty
List;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
  Creating file CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap
BUILD SUCCESS.

CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe...
C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\deploy.js(96, 5) WshShell.Exec: The system c
annot find the file specified.



C:\hello1>C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\run
WARNING: [ --target=<ID> | --emulator | --device ] not specified, defaulting to
--emulator
WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debu
g.

Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty
List;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
  Creating file CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap
BUILD SUCCESS.

CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe...
C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\deploy.js(96, 5) WshShell.Exec: The system c
annot find the file specified.



C:\hello1>C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\run --device
WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debu
g.

Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\hello1\platforms\wp8
toolsVersion 0 is not supported
        MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
buildCommand = %comspec% /c ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbu
ild" "C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\HelloWorldHP.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty
List;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorldHP -> C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.example.hello1.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
BUILD SUCCESS.

CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe...
C:\hello1\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\deploy.js(96, 5) WshShell.Exec: The system c
annot find the file specified.



C:\hello1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem and I think it's because I'm using Visual Studio Express to build WP8 app with.
When I go to open the SLN file for CordovaDeploy (in your platforms/wp8/cordova/lib directory) you'll see it says this version of Visual Studio can only build Windows Store apps and I expect you need the command line build version.

Work around is just to use the deploy system usually found in

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Phone SDK 8.0
```

named Application Deployment.

That said mine still isn't working and I get a funky unhelpful error of 0x8973190E there.
Using a Nokia Lumia630/VS Express 2013 on WP8 Pro.

Comment: Ok, sussed the 0x8973190E error too.  Was just the Nokia 630 was brand new and required updating to 8.1 and suddenly the error vanished.

(In case this indirectly fixed it too I installed my old VS2010 Premium  in the background as I was about to attempt to fix the CordovaDeploy.exe issue too)

Comment: sradforth is correct; I had a new Nokia Lumia435 running 8.1 and was getting this error when deploying using the "Windows Phone Application Deployment (8.1)" tool. Updating the phone resolved this.